# DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Maybe someone can help, how do I fix this?
I'm using hibernate, spring and gwt.

> com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException:
>   Service method 'public abstract void
>   com.yeah.client.service.PictureService.saveItem(com.yeah.shared.model.Picture)'
>   threw an       unexpected exception:
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   could not     insert:
>   [com.yeah.shared.model.Picture]; SQL
>   [insert into YeaH.Picture (albumID,
>   picLocation)   values (?, ?)];
>   constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
>   could not insert:
>   [com.yeah.shared.model.Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are inserting the object which fails to validate the constraint. (may be with same key)